# reorder radio button list

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below radio button list which is based on a multiple choice question, the information in the list will be added by a non technical user, I would like to know is there a method that i can use so the the list can be suffeled, each time the page has been loaded

```
<fieldset id="question1">
        <div id="scenario">
            QUESTION
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
        <div>
            Please select the correct answer: 
        </div>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="correct"> ANSWER ONE</input>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="wrong"> ANSWER TWO</input>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="wrong"> ANSWER THREE</input>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <br/><br/>
        <button type="button" id="answer" class="check" onclick="mark();" >Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: If this is not flat HTML, I'd recommend doing it server-side when the DOM is built (by shuffling your dataset) rather than mutating the existing DOM. In standard JavaScript this requires removing items from the DOM and re-adding them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this...

1. You need to add all labels under one div.

   ```
    <div class="list">
        <label>
             <input type="radio" name="q1" value="correct"> ANSWER ONE </input>
              <br />
         </label>
         <label> <input type="radio" name="q1" value="wrong"> ANSWER TWO </input>
          <br />
         </label>        

        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="q1" value="wrong"> ANSWER THREE </input>
         <br/>
       </label>
   </div>
   ```

Add following code in new shuffle.js file

```
  (function($){

   $.fn.shuffle = function() {

    var allElems = this.get(),
        getRandom = function(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        },
        shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
            var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
            allElems.splice(random, 1);
            return randEl;
       });

    this.each(function(i){
        $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
    });

    return $(shuffled);

}; 
  })(jQuery);
```

call to shuffle.js file Add following line of code in  script tag to shuffle

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $( '.list label' ).shuffle();
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the answer are in array you can use this method

```
function Shuffle(o) {
       for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
       return o;
};
```

then you can call like this

```
var testArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
Shuffle(testArray);
```

for more details you can visti this [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/shuffle-array/)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

1. Wrap all your answer labels in a `div` element, something like `<div id="answers"></div>`
2. Dispose of a `<br />` elements between labels, instead specifying a style `label {display: block;}`;
3. Apply following Javascript code

(with jQuery):

```
jQuery(function($){
    var answers = $("#answers");

    answers.html(
        answers.find("label").sort(function(){
            return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
        })
    );    
});
```

And you're good to go.

Here's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Df6/)

Comment: All i wanted to do was display the multiple answer in randrom order no the question

Comment: That's merely a naming issue :) fixing it right now.

Comment: I have tried this and it still isnt working, the page the i am using is a .htm is that why it could be causing me isse

Comment: Modified my code abit, and also, make sure you have `jQuery` library included at your page.