# shuffle multiple radio button groups and return them to the position

Tags: javascript, html

I'm implementing a quiz on which I have several question that are asked to the user. Each Questions has several answer possibilities given with a form element and radiobuttons.
For each of these questions of the quizz I want to shuffle them to change the order in which they appear when the side is loaded.
 I found an alike questions with: [reorder radio button list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990878/reorder-radio-button-list) and http://jsfiddle.net/r8Df6/ but it does not solve my problem as I have multiple groups of radio buttons and each groups needs to be shuffleded individually without knowing before how many questions a quiz will have.
Using Flask and Jinja2 my code in my html file looks pretty much like this:

```
{% for question_obj in quizz_obj.question %}
<form>

<div class="item">
        <label for="correct"> {{ question_obj.answer }}
            <input type=radio id="correct" name="answer" value="{{ question_obj.answer }}"
        </label>
        <label for="wrong1"> {{ question_obj.fake1}}
            <input type=radio id="wrong1" name="fake1" value="{{ question_obj.fake1}}"
        </label>
        <label for="wrong2"> {{ question_obj.fake2}}
            <input type=radio id="wrong2" name="fake2" value="{{ question_obj.fake2}}"
        </label>
        <label for="wrong3"> {{ question_obj.fake3}}
            <input type=radio id="wrong3" name="fake3" value="{{ question_obj.fake3}}"
        </label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Do you have any ideas on solving this problem?
As mentioned above I use flask, Jinja2 are there any useable methods for this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use an Array. In an example I built awhile back It uses an Object to store the question and possible answers. The first answer in the array is always the correct answer https://codepen.io/zfrisch/pen/LQKbJM?editors=0010

Comment: Actually as my backend is in Python is there also a way to do this with JQuery and Javascript on the rendered HTML?